# Adding a keylistener to a JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jmenubar

I have the following code for a JMenuBar. How would I add my key listener `CustomKeyListener` to the entire JMenuBar?

```
package UI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.font.*;
import UI.*;

public class GuiDMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    JMenu m_file,m_code;
    JMenuItem mi_f_new,mi_f_open;

    public GuiDMenuBar()
    {
        setBorderPainted(true);
        makeFileMenu();
        makeCodeButton();

    }

    void makeFileMenu()
    {
        m_file = new JMenu("File");
        m_file.setMnemonic('F');

        mi_f_new = new JMenuItem("New");
        mi_f_new.setMnemonic('N');
        mi_f_open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        mi_f_open.setMnemonic('O');

        mi_f_new.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control N"));
        mi_f_open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control O"));

        m_file.add(mi_f_new);
        m_file.add(mi_f_open);

        add(m_file);
    }

    void makeCodeButton()
    {
        m_code = new JMenu("Code");
        m_code.setMnemonic('C');

        add(m_code);
    }

    public void addListeners(ActionListener al)
    {
        mi_f_new.addActionListener(al);
        mi_f_open.addActionListener(al);
    }

    class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener
    {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Type");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Press");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Release");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding

```
    m_code.setFocusable(true);
    m_code.addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());
```

to the `void` `makeCodeButton` however that did not pick up when anything was typed for that one JMenu. This is why I want it added to the whole JMenuBar instead.

**Edit to show full CustomKeyListener**

```
class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener
{
    Robot Roby = null;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            if(m_code.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    Roby = new Robot();
                }

                catch(AWTException awte)
                {
                    awte.printStackTrace();
                }

                clcikComponent(m_file);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Type");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Press");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Release");
    }

    public void clcikComponent(Component comp)
    {
        Point p = comp.getLocationOnScreen();
        System.out.println(p);

        Roby.mouseMove(p.x,p.y);
        Roby.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Roby.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for key bindings instead...

Comment: Why do you want to listen for KeyEvents in a JMenu or JMenuBar?

Comment: So I can implement an if statement, in keyTyped()
char c = e.getKeyChar()
if(c==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
{
      if(m_code.isSelected())
      {
             //Do Something
      }
}

@copeg

Comment: @Dan, if statement to accomplish what? What exactly is the overall goal?

Comment: @copeg I will edit the code to show

Comment: @copeg I have updated the code to show that when m_code is selected and the key enter is selected it would activate a robot to click a different component (component is normally a button but changed it to m_file so it works properly with this code)

Comment: @Dan, I still don't understand the overall goal - or the need for a `KeyListener` - wouldn't an Action or `ActionListener` suffice?

Comment: Excuse the bad question but would an actionlistener or an action be able to pick up a key event like pressing enter while the m_code is selected? @copeg

Comment: I've read the question 3 times and still have no idea what you are trying to do. A JMenu does not and should not respond to events. It should just be used to display the menu items of the menu. When the menu items are visible and you use the Enter key, the `Action` of the selected menu item is invoked. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: `would an actionlistener or an action be able to pick up a key event` @Dan, no, but that's why I'm confused and back to my first question: why do you want to detect a KeyEvent? What is the requirement? Menu's are for Actions as @camickr commented

Comment: I am essentially trying to create a hotkey to activate the menu while it is selected. I am trying to do this so that when navigating through the menu bar with arrow keys you can activate the action this is meant to do. I am trying to do this as a workaround since unlike a JMenuItem which if it was selected and you clicked enter it would activate whatever you had set assuming you had a action listener on it

Comment: tl;dr but as par my understanding there's no way a menubar could gain focus, even if you call setFocusable(true).

Comment: Just noticed your last question about trying to add a JButton to the menu bar. Maybe the fact this is so difficult is telling you something? A JMenubar contains a JMenu which contains JMenuItem. Companies spend millions of dollars to create clean consistent UI's. Why are you trying to be different? `I am essentially trying to create a hotkey` - create a JMenu and add a JMenuItem to it. You can then define an accelerator for the menu item. Advance users will learn to use the accelerator as the hot key. The menu item provides self documentation for hot keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think this is a bad idea. As a user I would find it very confusing to find out that using the Enter key on one menu invokes an Action, while it doesn't do anything on other menus. The suggestion I gave in my comment is a far better solution.

However, I was curious why it didn't work and I found out that focus is actually on the JRootPane when the menu is displayed (and events are only dispatched to the component with focus). So you could add the KeyListener to the root pane.

However, there is an easier approach. You can use the `JMenu.addMenuKeyListener(...)` method. The interface is the same as a KeyListener except all methods include "menu" in the name.